# Stuck on a type mismatch error in Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I nearly solved how to process collisions. But I am stuck on one error. I Looked at the library and I don't understand still how to solve this error. My code is shown below.

final Array destructableBodies = new Array();

```
final Body destroyer2 = destroyBody;
final Array<Body> bodiesToDestroy = new Array<Body>();

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    System.out.println(delete);


    world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);
    if (delete = true)
    {   

        for(Body body : destructableBodies)
        {   
            if (delete = true)
            {
                System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 7");
                delete = false;
                world.destroyBody(body);
            }
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 8");
    }
    bodiesToDestroy.clear();
```

// in render method

world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
            Body bodyA = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
            Body bodyB = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
            // you can also use the user data to store information about the destructibility of bodies
            if(bodyA == destroyer2 && destructableBodies.contains(bodyB, true))
            {
                bodiesToDestroy.add(bodyB);
                System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 2");
                delete = true;
            }
            else if(bodyA == destroyer2 && destructableBodies.contains(bodyA, true))
            {
                bodiesToDestroy.add(bodyA);
                System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 3");
                delete = true;
            }
            destructableBodies.add(destroyBody);
            System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 4");
        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact arg0) {
            System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 5");
            reload();
            delete = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact arg0) {
            System.out.println("ENTRY POINT 6");
        }
    });
```

I have changed the code and the body is destroyed but my game crashes and I get the assertion failed error. And I also get body count < body capacity. I set up some print statements and found that every time a collision occurs it enters the for each loop twice and it deletes a body twice but only one body is created. Don't know what to do I even set up boolean flags but even that is not working.

Comment: Try defining your array as follows: Array<Body> bodiesToDestroy = new ArrayList<Body>();

Comment: error is fixed now but the bodies are not destroyed any ideas ?

Comment: use curly brackets for your for loop {}

Comment: I tried this and it is still not working :(

Comment: I updated my code and posted it above any ideas ?